# Volume keys not working after upgrade to Quantal, but work from MC Remote

Tags: upgrade, 12.10, keyboard

All keys worked perfectly in Precise. After upgrading to Quantal, multimedia keys on my USB keyboard no longer work (volume keys, play, next, prev).

Weird thing is that I've also got a cheap MC Remote (which shows up as an USB keyboard), and it works ok.

Any hints?